# Вложенный цикл Python остановился for j in range(1, x - i): на i = 3 и j = 1

Tags: python, циклы, for

Есть такой код

```
for i in range(1, (x := int(input()))):
    if i == 1:
        print('А Б В')
    for j in range(1, x - i):
        print(x - i)
        print(i, j, (x - i - j))
```

Возвращает такое

```
5
А Б В
4
1 1 3
4
1 2 2
4
1 3 1
3
2 1 2
3
2 2 1
2
3 1 1
```

Где:
5 - ввод,
АБВ - АБВ,
Одиночная цифра - ввод минус номер итерации.

Вопрос состоит в том, почему при достижении номера итерации i = 3, останавливается весь процесс, хотя чисто интуитивно, итерация должна продолжаться по j и по i принимать вид

```
2
3 2 0
2
3 3 -1
.
.
.
1
4 1 0
1
4 2 -1
```

и т.д.

Comment: Сколько раз выполняется цикл `for j in range(1, 1):` ?

Comment: Что должен делать код?

Comment: @Глеб 


Аня, Боря и Вова решили съесть апельсин.
Подскажите ребятам, как им его разделить. Напишите программу, которая выводит все возможные способы разделки апельсина.

Формат ввода
В единственной строке записано количество долек апельсина.

Формат вывода
Таблица вариантов разделения апельсина.

Примечания
Каждому ребёнку должна достаться хотя бы одна долька апельсина.
Ни одной дольки не должно остаться.
Выводить варианты в порядке увеличения количества долек у Ани, затем Бори и затем уже Вовы.

Comment: @MBo 0? Но ведь по сути при третьей итерации там получается `for j in range(1, 2):` ?

Comment: Это как раз выполняется `2   3 1 1`. А условие внесите в вопрос, отредактировав его. Вы, похоже, переусложняете решение.

Comment: @MBo в том и загвоздка, что решение - верное, а почему оно верное - я не понимаю к сожалению. Пытаюсь разобраться. Раз выполняется `2  3 1 1` при i = 3 и j = 1, то ведь должно выполняться и `2  3 2 0` i = 3, j = 2 и `2  3 3 -1` i = 3, j = 3, а цикл остановился на j = 1. Вот это для меня загвоздка.

Comment: Какие элементы входят в питоновский range(1, 2) ??